# Python grequests gets None responses

Tags: python, web-crawler, grequests

I'm crawling this website using grequests (at a pretty slow pace), and at the first few hundreds of requests I get mostly 200 HTTP responses, but at a certain point, all I get are None responses(without any raised exception).

The weirdest part is the if I try running the crawl again **while the first crawl is still running and getting None responses**, the second crawl received 200 responses.

By the way, I'm pretty sure the website I'm crawling doesn't have any kind of crawling protection.

This is my code:

```
for x in range(0, len(urls), JUMP):                 

    rs = (grequests.get(u, stream=False, headers = headers, 
    timeout = 300) for u in urls[x:x+JUMP])     
    responses += grequests.map(rs,exception_handler=nones_exception_handler)

# saves the failed requests so i can try those again later
def nones_exception_handler(request, exception): 
    nonlocal exceptionurls
    print(exception)
    exceptionurls.append(request.url)
```

Comment: What is `nones_exception_handler`? Does it return `None`?

Comment: @Blckknght It just saves the failed requests. I've edited the question.